# Categories and subcategories in Django/Wagtail

Tags: python, django, django-models, categories, wagtail

I'm trying to implement categories and subcategories for `question_answers` snippet in Wagtail/Django. I have defined the categories as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/.

The problem is that I am finding it difficult to implement subcategories for the categories that I defined and I cannot find a proper way to show them in Wagtail admin, as I am not sure which of the available panel types I should use from the ones that are available (https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/pages/panels.html). Also, preferably I want to use `CharField` for the names.

Ideally, I want them to be available to choose from in the admin panel, so that for example when I choose one of the categories, I get the subcategories for each.

What would be the best way to go about it?

Here's the code:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField

from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
    FieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
)

from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

class FaqPage(Page):

    max_count = 1

    slug = 'faq'
    template = 'faq/faq.html'

@register_snippet
class question_answer(models.Model):

    CATEGORIES = (
    ('GENERAL', 'General'),
    ('JOBS', 'Jobs'),
    ('LANGUAGES', 'Languages'),
    ('PROGRAM', 'Program'),
    ('REGISTRATION', 'Registration'),
    ('STUDIES', 'Studies'),
    ('SUPPORT', 'Support')
    )

    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, choices=CATEGORIES, default='Other'),
    question = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    answer = RichTextField(blank=False)

    panels = [
        FieldPanel('category'),
        FieldPanel('question'),
        FieldPanel('answer'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```